# spring Model is not filling automatically with json data

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have written some sort of code to send data from client to spring model. and want that json data should automatically fill the java class. but not able to do this.

Jquery looks like this

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(event){
        var username = $('#id_username').val();  
        var password = $('#id_password').val();
        alert(username + password)
        var json = { "loginId" : username, "password" : password};

      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: $("#login-form").attr("action"),
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            var mess = validateForm();
            if(mess.length != 0){
                $('#error-mes').show();
                $('#error-mes').html(mess);
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return true;
        },
        success: function(response){
             $('#error-mes').html(response);
             $('#error-mes').show();
        },  
        error: function(e){  
          alert('Error: ' + e);  
        }  
      });  
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#userName').hide();
      $('#spn_password').hide();
});
```

Spring code like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public @ResponseBody String submitCustSignInForm(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("model") Person model,
            HttpSession sess) {

        String response = "";
        Person person = null;

        if (sess.getAttribute("USER_INFO") == null) {
            person = tsService.login(model);
            if (person == null) {
                response = "User name or password does not match.";
            } else {
                response = "success";
                sess.setAttribute("USER_INFO", person);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Person model has same loginId and password attribute and setter and getter in class.

can some body tell me how can it achieved.

Comment: model == null?? What debug says?

Comment: You are posting JSON as the body of the request not as parameters so `@ModelAttribute` will not work as that expects request parameters. Use `@RequestBody` instead.

Comment: i user @RequestBody annotation too. but in the case i got another error that is 'invalid token character ',' in token "x-www-form-urlencoded,'

Comment: Fix that error, adding `@ModelAttribute` isn't going to fix that. To get the object you will need `@RequestBody`. Problably your request is garbled.

Comment: so how can i trace debug this error. or what can be possible reason for this error.

Comment: configure log4j in your application and set it to debug mode, then see your log file for detailed error